# What is an efficient algorithm to perform a one-bit logical shift of an integer variable?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Let a and b be two integer variables with value >=0. To shift the binary bit sequence representing a (e.g. 10110010 for a=178) one bit to the left (i.e. into b=01100100=100) you can duplicate a and then take away 2^n, where n ist the bit length of the binary representation of a,  so that b=a+a-2^n.
However, this algorithm takes O(n), where n is the number of bits in the sequence, and is in practice not viable for sequences of upwards of 10000 bits.
What is a more efficient alternative whose efficiency does not depend on the length of the bit chain?

Comment: You need to specify how you store the data. For example if it's in a linked list operation can be O(1).

Comment: Hmm... ok, I'll edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the surrounding computation, you could consider a denormalized representation (e.g., for Collatz, instead of the even/odd test, iterate by multiplying by 3 and adding the value of the lowest order set bit).

Comment: "not viable" for 10k bits sounds rather extreme to me, with 64bit limbs that would be about 160 iterations of a nearly-trivial loop.. sure it's not nearly as fast as a single elementary operation, but it's not like that operation is going to take a macroscopic amount of time either

Comment: @nicomp Breaking up the sequence definitely sounds like a good idea!

Comment: I don't "get" the role of `b`. Depending on other operations needed, normalise aligning to the rightmost one and store the number of trailing zeroes: a shift corresponds to in- or decreasing this count, possibly removing a one "shifted out"

Comment: I voted to close this question since it is still unclear how you store the bit sequence (for instance in an array of `int`s representing 64 bits each; or in a linked list of `int`s representing 1 bit each). Please edit your question. You may also want to add a programming language to the tags. This allows us to give you an implementation and may also attract more users.